# Access Multidimensional Array element with out knowing parent elements

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have function that returns the following multidimensional array. I don't have control of how the array is formed. Im trying to access the 'Result' elements. This issue is, the name of the parent elements constantly changing. The location of the 'Result' element is always the same (as the is the name "Result"). Is it possible to access that element without know the name of the parent elements?

```
    Array
(
    [sHeader] => Array
        (
            [aAction] => ActionHere
        )

[sBody] => Array
    (
        [CreatePropertyResponse] => Array
            (
                [CreatePropertyResult] => Array
                    (
                        [Message] => Successfully completed the operation
                        [Result] => 0
                        [TransactionDate] => 2013-05-19T21:54:35.765625Z
                        [bPropertyId] => 103
                    )

            )

    )
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy option to search the array keys/values recursively is to use a recursive iterator; these are built-in classes, part of the [Standard PHP Library](http://php.net/spl).

```
$result   = false;
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));
foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
    if ($key === 'Result') {
        $result = $value;
        break;
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

The bonus here is that you could, if you wanted to, check the depth of the `Result` item (`$iterator->getDepth()`) in the array structure and/or check one or more ancestor keys (`$iterator->getSubIterator(…)->key()`).

Answer (score 0):

If the parent elements have only one child, you can solve it by getting the only element given back by `array_keys()`, and going two levels deep.

Anyway, if your array changes *that* much, and you systematically have to access a nested property, you have a design issue for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:  array_column won't actually work in this case.  You could search through each level, recursively, until you find the given key.  Something like:

```
function find_key_value($array, $search_key) {
    if (isset($array[$search_key])) return $array[$search_key];
    $found = false;
    foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
         if (is_array($value)) $found = find_key_value($value, $search_key);
         if ($found) return $found; 
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `array_column` just makes a pluck, but does not go in arbitrary depth, isn't it?

Comment: only searches 1 dimensional array

Answer (score 0):

```
function findkeyval($arr,$key) {
    if(isset($arr[$key])) {
        return $arr[$key];
    }else {
        foreach($arr as $a) {
            if(is_array($a)) {
                $val=findkeyval($a,$key);
                if($val) {
                   return $val;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```